# Is there a better way of saying "writing for fun"?

Tags: word-choice

As in "...written several pieces for **fun**."

Writing "for recreational purposes" doesn't sit right, and I can't think of anything else.

Comment: My first wife, a stage designer, used to speak of doing sketches "for my own amazement".

Comment: What's wrong with "for fun"? That's the best reason in the world. It's certainly the only reason I participate in ELU, that's for sure.

Comment: @JohnLawler: +1 for *for fun*.  And it is pretty simple to look for synonyms for *fun* - pretty much any of them can be used with *writing pieces for ____*.

Comment: There's nothing _wrong_ with it, I guess. It's just that when I'm attempting to write with an academic register, "fun" doesn't seem to fit in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write something for *pleasure* may come close to your idea.

[Reasons To Write: Write for Pleasure](http://writersontherise.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/reasons-to-write-writing-for-pleasure/)

> I had been teaching writing for about a year when I noticed something about writing for pleasure vs. writing for publication. Both intentions seemed to produce equally strong results for my writing students. In fact, when comparing writing assignments between the two classes, I often felt students in my writing for pleasure classes were producing superior results compared to my writing for publication students.

Source:http://writersontherise.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/reasons-to-write-writing-for-pleasure/

Comment: This would be my choice. To me, "...for fun" carries more of a dismissive connotation.

Answer (score 1):

If the writing is done on a regular basis, then you could say "writing as a hobby".

[Google](https://www.google.com/#q=define%3ahobby) defines *hobby* as "an activity done regularly in one's leisure time for pleasure."

Answer (score 0):

Try “I wrote these pieces for diversion” or “I wrote these pieces as diversions” *([diversion](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/diversion)* sense 2).

Time was—in the fifth century B.C., in Greece—when employing the medium of writing at all (as opposed to oration) was considered inherently non-serious.

Comment: It's also common coin -- especially with the better ones -- to say that you wrote them as an exercise and never intended to publish them. This is a good test to see whether this editor will believe anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try “I wrote these pieces for personal edification” I think it manages to avoid verbosity and more succinctly describes the nature of fun.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly informal, though I'm not certain of your angle here.
I've written several articles/stories/texts just messing/playing about.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I would try to keep words as plain as possible. "I am writing words for leisure."

Comment: This doesn't sound at all colloquial to my ear (British English speaker).